# Asio Boost - win_iocp_io_context::timer_thread_function stuck waiting after stopping the context and acceptor

Tags: boost-asio

I've got a web server based off the [advanced_server.cpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/beast/example/advanced/server/advanced_server.cpp) example on the boost site and I'm trying to have it start, service some requests, stop and then restart listening to a different socket without stopping the process.

When I do this sequence most times it just works. Occasionally (not always) I get stuck during stop when I'm attempting to std::thread::join() my running io_context threads. When I look at my running threads one of them is stuck in this timer wait in win_iocp_io_context.ipp

```
struct win_iocp_io_context::timer_thread_function
{
  void operator()()
  {
    while (::InterlockedExchangeAdd(&io_context_->shutdown_, 0) == 0)
    {
      **if (::WaitForSingleObject(io_context_->waitable_timer_.handle,
            INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) // Stuck here infinitely. **
      {
        ::InterlockedExchange(&io_context_->dispatch_required_, 1);
        ::PostQueuedCompletionStatus(io_context_->iocp_.handle,
            0, wake_for_dispatch, 0);
      }
    }
  }

  win_iocp_io_context* io_context_;
};
```

My stop procedure is to close the acceptor, stop all open sockets and then calling stop on the iocontext like this:

```
// Acceptor close
_acceptor.cancel();
_acceptor.close();
_acceptor.release();

{
    // Waiting for the acceptor's async_accept handler to get the cancellation error_code
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    _cvShutdown.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(1000), [this]() { return _shutdownComplete;    });
}

// Socket close
_socket.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send, errorCode);
_socket.cancel();
_socket.close();

// Now shutting down the io_context
_ioContext.stop();

for (const auto& upThread : _httpThreadPool)
{
    if (upThread->joinable())
    {
        upThread->join();
    }
}
```

I think the .cancel() calls should happen as part of .close(), but was being exhaustive. _httpThreadPool is a set of std::threads just calling _iocontext.run().

Am I missing something in the stop process here? Is there a way to make sure that this timer_thread_function gets shut down and doesn't end up stuck waiting for a handle on an already stopped io_context_?

Library version is 1.78.0, versions: Visual C++ : 14.33.31629, Windows SDK : 10.0.22000, MSBuild 17.5.0.

Comment: "stop all open sockets"? Also, can you perhaps show a self-contained reproducer? Mention compiler + library versions. I understand it won't be deterministic. Consider posting the issue at https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues if you make a reproducer.

Comment: Sorry, close all open sockets (as in sockets processing requests received by the acceptor just prior to the stop that haven't responded yet are closed). Library version is 1.78.0, versions: Visual C++  : 14.33.31629, Windows SDK : 10.0.22000, MSBuild 17.5.0. I'll work on getting a reproducer.